# Why can't I use my history brush in photoshop cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a beginner in photoshop and I have a question.
Why can't I use my history brush..? It shows this pop up: 
[image]

How can i fix it now?

Comment: Do you have history states? have you set the state you want to brush in?  http://tv.adobe.com/videos/history-brush/

Comment: No I don't have history states, but i think i have to do something on image>canvas size

Comment: If you have no history states, what do you anticipate the *history* brush doing?

Comment: Welcome Liliana! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers. If you want to know more about GD.SE, please see the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Actions such as cropping, trimming, using the Image Size or Canvas Size commands, or rotating any amount other than 180 degrees can prevent you from going back to a previous state and will give you this error message.

I would suggest using the tool first and then making further changes.

Read more here: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-history-brush-tool-in-photoshop-cs6.html